# Mysql service not started homestead mac

Tags: mysql, vagrant, virtualbox, homestead

I am using **MAC** when I run this command **vagrant up --provision** got the error **Invalid feature: mysql**, I tried vagrant halt and run the vagrant up --provision command again then still mysql service not started

**Error**

```
==> homestead: Running provisioner: shell...
homestead: Running: inline script
homestead: Invalid feature: mysql

==> homestead: Running provisioner: enable mysql (shell)...
homestead: Running: inline script
homestead: Synchronizing state of mysql.service with SysV service script with       /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install.
homestead: Executing: /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install enable mysql
```

**Homestead version**

```
'origin/release'
```

**Homestead.yml**

```
ip: "192.168.56.0"
memory: 2048
cpus: 2
provider: virtualbox

authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
- ~/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:
- map: ~/code
  to: /home/vagrant/code

sites:
- map: homestead.test
  to: /home/vagrant/code/public

databases:
- homestead

features:
- mysql: true
- mariadb: false
- postgresql: false
- ohmyzsh: false
- webdriver: false

services:
- enabled:
      - "mysql"
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that the error comes from:

[image: Homestead.yaml example]

Please, try to put comments there as in the example below:

[image: comments]

OR use this code:

```
 services:
    -
        enabled: [mysql]
```

Finally, run the command `vagrant reload --provision`.